# Complex Join Using LINQ EF

Tags: linq, entity-framework, join

How can I join the two queries using LINQ to EF?  I need the result set returned to me that includes joined data from the 2 queries combined.

## 1

```
select StockNo, Description 
from VehicleOption_New 
where StockNo in 
(
    select v.StockNo
    from Vehicles v
    join StatusDescription s 
    on v.Status = s.StatusId
    where NewOrUsed = 'n' and v.model = 'cts' 
)
and color is not null
```

## 2

```
select v.StockNo, s.StatusDescriptionText
from Vehicles v
join StatusDescription s 
on v.Status = s.StatusId
where NewOrUsed = 'n' and v.model = 'cts'
```

Comment: What do your equivalent EF queries look like?

Comment: By join, you do really mean a SQL join? i.e. you want the results of 1 plus the StatusDescriptionText from the Vehicles table too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have the equivalent EF queries you can use either `Concat()` or `Union()` to combine the results.